# Storing values on a key(object) using Javacript es5

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying toget some Tags from a XML file and their respective Names and Values, and I want to store the Names as a Key in a object and their Values on the same object, I want to store the Values as an Array but instead the values concatenat. I'm using DOM Parser to get the info.

for exemplo, I'm getting this output:

```
[
  { returnValue: ['0'] },
  { returnComment: [''] },
  { B: ['135136137138139'] },
  { P: ['00000'] },
  { PD: ['00000'] },
  { Type: ['06050605060506050605'] },
  { n: ['5'] },
];
```

and I want this output:

```
[
  { returnValue: ['0'] },
  { returnComment: [''] },
  { B: ['135,136,137,138,139'] },
  { P: ['0,0,0,0,0'] },
  { PD: ['0,0,0,0,0'] },
  { Type: ['0605,0605,0605,0605,0605'] },
  { n: ['5'] },
];
```

```
 var childNodesByName=doc.getElementsByTagName(wantedNode).item(0).getChildNodes();

 var nodeArWithValues = [];
 var nodeName;
 for (var w = 0; w < childNodesByName.length; w++) {
    var obj = {};
    nodeName = childNodesByName.item(w).nodeName;
    var nodeValue = childNodesByName.item(w).getTextContent();
    bj[nodeName] = nodeValue;
    nodeArWithValues.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. What's your question? Do you observe unexpected behavior that you can't explain?

Comment: You probably have to loop through`childNodesByName.item(w).childNodes`. The `.getTextContent()` is concatenating them togehter

Comment: @adiga, Thanks for the help, I'm trying to work around it, but still didn't figure it out, without the .getTextContent() I can get the values inside the childNodes.